# Usage of uint_8, uint_16 and uint_32

Tags: c, typedef, fread, cs50

Please explain each case in detail, what is happening under the hood and why I am getting 55551 and -520103681 specifically.

```
typedef uint_8 BYTE;        

BYTE arr[512];
fread(arr, 512, 1, infile);
printf("%i", arr[0]);
```

**OUTPUT :255**

```
typedef uint_16 BYTE;        

BYTE arr[512];
fread(arr, 512, 1, infile);
printf("%i", arr[0]);
```

**OUTPUT :55551**

```
typedef uint_32 BYTE;        

BYTE arr[512];
fread(arr, 512, 1, infile);
printf("%i", arr[0]);
```

**OUTPUT :-520103681**

I am reading from a file having first four bytes as 255 216 255 244.

Comment: `256*216+255 = 55551`. Same thing in last case, but you also print __unsigned integer__ as __signed__

Comment: If you don't use some dog poop "uint_8" but C standard `uint8_t`, then you can `#include <inttypes.h> printf("%"PRIu8", arr[0]);` to get the correct format specifier.

Comment: You forgot to mention why you are confused. What did you expect to see instead?

Comment: Such a typedef `typedef uint_32 BYTE;` is a good way to annoy any colleague. You should **never ever** create such a confusing definition.

Comment: In addition to Gerhardh: If something is called `BYTE`, probably anybody would expect a byte. In your case, you should use a better suitable name. Why not `Value` or `Item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your 3 cases, before the printf statement, the 4 first bytes of the `arr` array (in hexadecimal format) are: FF D8 FF E0, which corresponds to 255 216 255 224.

Here are explanations of each case:

1. `arr[0]` has uint8_t type, so its 1-byte value is 0xFF, so `printf("%i", arr[0]);` prints 255, which corresponds to 0xFF in signed decimal integer format required by `%i`, integer size being 4 bytes.
2. `arr[0]` has uint16_t type, so its 2-bytes value is 0xFFD8, so `printf("%i", arr[0]);` prints 55551, which corresponds to 0xFFD8 in signed decimal integer format required by `%i`, integer size being 4 bytes. Note that 0xFFD8 is interpreted with little-endianness (the byte 0xD8 is the MSB).
3. `arr[0]` has uint32_t type, so its 4-bytes value is 0xFFD8FFE0, so `printf("%i", arr[0]);` prints -520103681, which corresponds to 0xFFD8FFE0 in **signed** decimal integer format required by `%i`, integer size being 4 bytes. Note that 0xFFD8FFE0 is interpreted with little-endianness (the byte 0xE0 is the MSB).

*Note: I voluntarily changed "255 216 255 244" from your post into "255 216 255 224". I think you made a typo.*

Answer (score 0):

You seem to mixup a lot of misunderstandings. Three out of four lines in your examples are questionable. So let's disect them.

`typedef uint_8 BYTE;` why do you have this typedef and where is `uint_8` coming from I suggest you just use `uint8_t` from `stdint.h` and for a minimal example you could skip your typedef to byte completly.

The [documentation of fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/) tells us that:

- the second parameter is the size of each element to be read
- the third parameter is the number of elements to be read

There are other ways to get the values into memory and to make the program reproducable by copy and paste we can just enter the corresponding values to memory. If you have problems with fread that would be a different question.

So it would be one of those lines (your last value has to be 224 not 244 to get -520103681)

```
uint8_t arr[512] ={0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0}; //{255, 216, 255, 224}
uint16_t arr[512] = {0xD8FF, 0xF4FF };//{255<<8 + 216, 255<<8 + 224} reversed because of the endianess
uint32_t arr[512] = {0xE0FFD8FF}; //{255<<24 + 216<<16 + 255<<8 + 224}
```

Now you can see that the arrays are of different size and 16/32 bit hardly qualify as a `BYTE`

In the last line you use [`printf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) wrong. If you look up the output and length specifiers for `printf()` you can see that `i` is used for `int` (which probably is 32bit).

Basically you tell it read `arr[0]` (of whatever type) as signed int.
This results in the values you see above. The (nearly) correct specifiers would be `%hhu` for `unsigned char`, `%hu` for `unsigned short` and `%u` for `unsigned int`.

But as you use size defined variables it would be better to use [`inttypes.h`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cinttypes/) and the specifiers :

`PRIu8, PRIu16 and PRIu32` accordingly like this

```
printf("%"PRIu8,arr[0]);
```

putting them all together yields:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void)
{
  uint32_t arr[512] = {0xE0FFD8FF};
  printf("%"PRIu32,arr[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

---

If you make eleminate all the problems in the code we get closer to the problem.
Problem 1 might have been that you forgot about endianess so you might expect the bytes in a different order.

Also if you use the signed specifier for `printf` and the MSB is 1 you get a negative value, that won't happen if you use the correct specifier for unsigned values.